# Intellij Idea keeps resetting compiler to 'ajc'

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Very often, when I change my Maven Projects settings (add/remove modules, change profile, refresh dependencies) - Idea resets Java Compiler (under Settings->Build->Compiler->Java Compiler) - to Ajc.

This is very annoying, because I use Javac for my project. And I feel like its very old bug, because I stumbled across it in earlier versions.

Is there any solution to stop Idea resetting default compiler to Ajc?

Thank you.

Comment: That is the AspectJ compiler.  Do you have AspectJ code somewhere in your project that trigger IntelliJ to think you need it?

Comment: Do you have "aspectj-maven-plugin" added to your project pom.xml? Pom file is used as initial source of project configuration, so if "aspectj-maven-plugin" is used, Ajc will be selected as compiler.

Answer (score 4):

Go to intellij preference and do

1. go to "build and execution -> build tools -> maven-> importing" and unselect "detect compiler automatically" [image: likethis]
2. go to "build and execution -> compiler -> java compiler" and in the Use compiler dropdown select java [image: likethis]

Peace

Answer (score 2):

If "aspectj-maven-plugin" is used.
Add 'skip' configuration, cheat 'aspectj support plugin' .

```
<plugin> 
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.11</version>
  <configuration>
    <skip>true</skip>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <configuration>
        <skip>false</skip>
      </configuration>
      <goals>
        <goal>compile</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```